# How to configure JPA JTA in MFP Java Adapter

Tags: jpa, ibm-mobilefirst

I could use OpenJpa JPA Resource_Local successfully, but encounter block while trying to configure JPA JTA in MFP Java adapter... Is there a way for it in Mobilefirst Platform Java Adapter?

Comment: What is the block? What is the error? What are you encountering?

Comment: I wonder to use the JPA JTA in MFP. Below is part of my persistence.xml.                                                                                                                                                                           <persistence-unit name="testpu" transaction-type="JTA">                               <provider>
            org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
        </provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/test_ds</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>

Comment: Also, I added datasource in the MFP Service Liberty. But I could not get EntityManager in the Java Adapter. Is there way to get the JPA EntityManager using JPA JTA Way in MFP?

Answer (score 0):

MFP is using OpenJPA v1.2.2 . What JPA version did you try to use ?

Comment: I am using the OpenJPA v1.2.2 provided by MFP. Not include new libraries.